# Match first and last part of an element ID with css

Tags: css, selenium, css-selectors

My Html code is `FirstStep_CustomDates_e1baeca1-5e06-43f2-96fc-5fd3f262c5fd__Value_timepicker`

The numbers in between "FirstStep_customeDates" and "_Value_timepicker" will change dynamically.

The requirement is i should match the text that is prefix and suffix to the number

```
css=a[id^='FirstStep_customeDates' and id$='_Value_timepicker']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can combine those requirements like this:

```css
a[id^='FirstStep_CustomDates'][id$='_Value_timepicker'] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="FirstStep_CustomDates_e1baeca1-5e06-43f2-96fc-5fd3f262c5fd__Value_timepicker">I should be red</a>
<br>
<a href="" id="FirstStep_CustomDates_e1baeca1-5e06-43f2-9dssdffssdf6fc-5fd3f262c5fd__Value_timepicker">I should be red</a>
<br>
<a href="" id="test">I should not be red</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please reference https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

> E[foo^="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly
>   with the string "bar"
>
> E[foo$="bar"] an E element whose "foo" attribute value ends exactly
>   with the string "bar"

Here is an example:

```css
div[id$="Value_timepicker"] {
  color:red
}

div[id^="FirstStep_CustomDates"] {
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="FirstStep_CustomDates_e1baeca1-5e06-43f2-96fc-5fd3f262c5fd__Value_timepicker">one div</div>
```